# Inequalities and absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

My book asks that if $$-5\leq x\leq 1$$ then find the boundaries of absolute value of $x$. Can you please help me in finding that?

Comment: please define "boundaries of absolute value".  Note that some answerers interpreted it differently.

Answer (score 2):

The midpoint of $[-5,1]$ is $-2$; the distance from $-2$ to both $-5$ and $1$ is $3$.  Hence the solution you seek is $$|x-(-2)|\le 3$$
or $$|x+2|\le 3$$

Answer (score 1):

$$-5\leq x \leq 1$$
$$-5+2\leq x+2 \leq 1+2$$
$$-3\leq x+2 \leq 3$$
$$|x+2|\leq3$$

Comment: +1. May I ask you to inform me about an ISI maths journal in your erea which covers semigroups or abstract algebra. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find a number $\alpha$ so that
\begin{align*}
-5 + \alpha &= -\beta \\
1+\alpha &= +\beta
\end{align*}
for some number $\beta$. Then
$$
-\beta = -5+\alpha \leq x +\alpha \leq 1+\alpha = \beta.
$$
That is, you'll obtain $-\beta \leq x+\alpha \leq \beta$. This will give you $|x+\alpha|\leq \beta$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the replies you received might be a little overwhelming.
1. By definition $|z| \geq 0$ for any $z$ (in other words an absolute value can never be less than 0). Since 0 is within the range of $x$ you were given then 0 is your low boundary.
2. On a (finite) range $[a,b]$ the maximum boundary is the maximum of $-a$ and $b$. In this case $-a$ is$-(-5)$ which is $5$ which is greater then $b$ which is $1$.
So your boundaries are $[0, 5]$